# read textfile into excel array and calculate average

Tags: c#, arrays, streamreader

I am trying to get the info in a textfile (which is just 6 lines of 5 numbers) to read into a 2D array, and add a new column for the average.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
public static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string file="marks2D.txt";
        string outfile="average.csv";
        StreamReader sr= new StreamReader(file);
        StreamWriter outstream= new StreamWriter(outfile);
        //double[] field=new double [0];
        string[,] temp=new string[5,6];
        int num=0;
        double ave=0;
        for(int i=0; i<temp.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            double sum=0;
            string line=sr.ReadLine();
            //temp=line.Split(',');
            for(int j=0; j<temp.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
            double m=double.Parse(line);
            ave = m/5;
                temp[num]=line;
                outstream.WriteLine(ave);
                //Console.Write("{0,1}", temp[i,j]);
            }
            outstream.WriteLine(field[num]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        sr.Close();
        outstream.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Might there be a question somewhere ...?

Comment: and an input example...